# Concatenating folders to be referred by a single name

Tags: windows-7

On Windows 7 Ultimate 64 I have some folders that must remain separate but, also, should be accessed as they were one single folder by a sync application. My purpose is actually very trivial but having such a tool could be very interesting: I would like to sync pictures from different folders all together to a phone, e.g.

`PicFolder=PicFolder1+PicFolder2+PicFolder9` and then sync on PicFolder, name to be made ​​available by the operating system to apps as if it were a real folder.

Note that creating a library is not the solution, it only groups folders into a container but you can't refer the library name to obtain its content. If you try to access the library via iTunes it says: "you have selected a library, not a folder". If we were in MVS Environment and want to concatenate partitioned datasets we could write

```
//mylib DD DSN=library1,... .
//      DD DSN=library2,... .
//      DD DSN=library9,... .
```

and we'll be able to access all member of the 3 libraries just referring 'mylib' data definition and any program that you call in that JCL described environment could use all or any member of the 3 libraries no matter which one contains it. So JCL creates the environment for the single running of a program, Windows by itself do not.

Answer (score 0):

You can realise this via Libraries, just create a custom library and add all folders you want to it, the library should then contain all files (and subfolders) from all chosen folders.

Comment: If the PC-phone sync app he's using supports Libraries then this would be the simplest solution.

Comment: I edited the question, please read again, thank you!